# Prototype JavaScript working locally in all browsers, but not in IE9 on server

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I am using Prototype version 1.6.0.2 in action here:

http://sgm189.csesalford.com/invoices

please login with username 'billy' password 'billy'

Go to Invoices > new invoice. Then try filling numeric data in the fields 'Sales Tax', 'Qty' and 'Price'.

In all browsers but IE9 the fields dynamically refresh and everything works. Another strange symptom is that the code works locally in IE9. UTF-8 encoded and no BOM.

Are there any revisions I can make to my code? Code available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fqe5d/

Comment: Just downloaded IE9 on my computer (just for you :)), and verified that this is happening for me too. IE8 was working though.. hmm. It works fine when I hit the "Compatibility View" button in the address bar (looks like a paper ripped in half, horizontally).

Comment: Thats was very well observed, I wonder what it means. Does Compatibility View revert it to IE8? I had best read up. Maybe this version of Prototype does not work with IE9.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe? Is the javascript you put in JSFiddle complete? It looks like its only a partial. Nevermind, copied and pasted it from invoice.js, I am going to step through it now.. I put an alert at the top and the bottom, and only the alert at the top is firing in jsfiddle.

Comment: I have since updated the file :)

Comment: Worked for me. IE9. Hit F12, click console and go through the process. See if you get any errors.

Comment: So this is without compatibility mode Salman A? My console is returned no errors upon going through the process. For me in IE9 'add new line' is working and nothing else. Running a quick reinstall of IE9.

Comment: Alright, I kind of have something.. After dynamically messing with the javascript, I've found that the inject() calls in your subtotal function are not working correctly. In a vanilla install of IE9, they are always returning the value 0, regardless of what I return. In Chrome, when I change the onchange event, though, they return whatever I return. I will continue to testing to find out why. Thanks a lot Salman for the F12 hint about IE9, this is allowing me to change the javascript on the fly for debugging purposes.

Comment: Abelito the error has been fixed by updating the Prototype Framework to the latest version. May I please apologise if you have invested a lot of time on this issue.

Comment: no problems at all lol, glad to hear it's fixed! and don't feel bad, i happily learned a lot while debugging prototype and its recursion methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Update your prototype! That should probably fix it :)